# VS 2022 Style Rule to keep Auto-Implemented Properties on One Line

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, editorconfig

When I cut & paste the following C# text in VS 2022:

```
public int? Units { get; set; }
```

it pastes it formatted as:

```
public int? Units
{
    get; set;
}
```

What .editorconfig rule needs to be adjusted to tell VS that I want my auto-implemented properties to remain on a single line?

Also, for heartfelt bonus points (but no actual points), is there a good way of finding this information myself?  I googled this until my eyes bled, and I searched the options under Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Code Style for as long as I could, with no luck.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for the `Automatically format on paste` setting? See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-text-editor-csharp-formatting?view=vs-2022#general-settings 

This would be located in Options -> TextEditor -> C# -> CodeStyle - Formatting -> General

Comment: @Ibrennan208 good suggestion; thank you!  Though I am still looking to configure the .editorconfig/style cop rules so that I can comfortably use them to format whole documents.  Currently I'm struggling to get several things to format as I desire, and this is top of the list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the .editorconfig UI, it is:

```
Whitespace -> Wrapping preferences -> Leave block on single line (checked)
```

In the .editorconfig file, add:

```
csharp_preserve_single_line_blocks = true
```

While this question is now answered, I still find myself frustrated trying to figure out how to *find* these options in these instances when I can't think of the right word or phrase to search by.  To a certain extent it just requires luck, which does not make for a happy code monkey.

Comment: I tried changing a whole bunch of settings to do this but couldn't find the right one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In the settings window: Text Editor->C#->Code Style->Formatting -> Wrapping -> Leave block on single line